# putting \psframebox with the left corner coordinate in PSTricks

Tags: pstricks

Using the auto-generated codes by LaTeXdraw, I put a text box with the following code in PSTricks:

```
\rput(9, -1){\psframebox[linewidth=0.04,fillstyle=solid]{Text Goes Here}}
```

I guess the coordinate `(9,-1)` corresponds to the center of the text box. Can I assign the coordinate for the left-top corner of the text box?  I wanted to put several text boxes vertically and arrange them with the left sides of the boxes aligned.

Comment: Are you working in centimeter for all settings like `linewidth=0.04`? In my personal opinion, `linewidth` is usually set in `pt` rather than in `cm`.

Comment: @xport  Thanks for the suggestion. I used LaTeXdraw and it created the codes with cm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `\rput[lb](...){...}` for left bottom